# Increase number of supported request by django on dev

Tags: python, django

I have a doc project where I have to test a massive number of urls and links.

To do that I was using python 2 linkchecker.

I upgraded to django 2.2 and python 3.6 and I am using a go binary called muffet (https://github.com/raviqqe/muffet).

linkchecker was gentle with the server, muffet on the other hand is more brutal (even with timeout options and other settings).

The problem I have is after some time, the requests timeout and the django local server crashes.

I heard about some kind of queue or cache for the local django server.

Is anyone knows how to increase the django limit in order not to DDOS myself while I am running my tests before deployment (this tool is not running in production).

Or any out of the box thinking to solve this.

Just for you to know, I run the server in background, and call the tool on the localhost url.

(from another terminal)

Thanks

Edit: https://github.com/django/django/blob/fba5d3b6e63fe4a07b1aa133186f997eeebf9aeb/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L58 this seems something I can play with?

Comment: Do you run a proper wsgi server?

Comment: just the python manage.py runserver for dev, the real server run on ngix

Comment: Then run a proper wsgi server locally. `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` are good for that. `waitress ` may be a good choice for that need, too.

Comment: I will investigate this way then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, like using a proper server within the container and runing `muffet` command like `muffet -t 30 -c 30 http://127.0.0.1` solve the issue.

Thanks to @Antwane to point me in the right direction ;)